# Not compiling CocoaPod FacebookCore

Tags: swift, xcode, facebook, cocoapods

My project not compiling CocoaPod FacebookCore. And when cloning project, break and other libraries. My project on Swift 3 and this lib on 2.3, swift legacy is true.

[This error photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/px2Zz.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try re- install the cocoa pods and quit the Xcode and run again.

Comment: I'm trying
1) close project - pod install - open project
2) remove pod 'FacebookCore' - close project - pod install - open project - add close project - pod install - open project - close project - pod install - open project
but it did not help